# eSignature endpoints reattempt protocol

Tags: docusignapi

I need to use `createEnvelope` and `getEnvelope`. For each endpoint, is there a recommended reattempt protocol?

It appears that 400 is the only possible error code. Would we reattempt on certain error messages?

Now I am typing to hit 220 characters :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your app runs in unreliable internet conditions - you can consider implementing a retry mechanism, but that's rare. I would also advise to only ever retry once, never more than once.

DocuSign servers are 99.999% reliable and are all over the world, which means you don't have to worry about issues on the DocuSign side of things.

The APIs are deterministic and would respond the same way each time.

a 400 error means something is wrong with your code/app and you have to fix it, retrying the same exact call would not do any good.

I would not worry/consider a reattempt mechanism for your app, but make sure your app works correct first. Then if you have it running in production, with real users, for a while and you see the need - you may consider it, but only after thorough investigation of the reasons for the failures.